# Smart Device application for Windows Mobile

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, smart-device

I installed Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK and tried to create new Smart Device project in VS2008. I expected to see a form like a mobile device in editor, however I just see a regular windows form, and application cannot be built.

Did anyone have same behavior? May be some additional componets should be installed or some configuration required?

Comment: What is the error message when it cannot be built?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all version of Visual Studio have the Smart Device pieces included. Is it Visual Studio 2008 *Professional* or better (i.e. not Express or Standard)?

Visual Studio also has the choice at installation to exclude pieces. Does your installation have the Smart Device Programming bits installed (re-run the installer to check)?

Comment: Sure, it's VS2008 Professional, with full components installed (Smart Device also included). I am able to create Smart Device project, but not able to work with it.

Comment: Try opening one of the sample smartdevice projects at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\Common\CS and C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CS (I ASSUME YOU ARE TALKING ABOUT C#)

Comment: Same behaviour. I see just windows form when open it. Projects from common folder cannot be built and give me a lot of errors. However projects from from PocetPC folder successfully built and runs on emulator (but I also see just windows form there in editor). What is diagnosis here? :)

Comment: I assume you VS2008 install is broken. You may try a reset; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=vs.80%29.aspx, If not OK, re-install Windows Mobile 6 SDK. If all worse, re-install VS2008 and then WM6 SDK d´from scratch.

Comment: I made full VS reinstall, installed service pack, installed SDK again and it finally work! Thanks all for support.